# Merge [cabal] and [cabal-install] tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I am not sure if the original intent was to use one flag for the cabal library and the other for the actual executable/tool but in practice there doesn't seem to be any distinction on how the tags are used.

At the moment [cabal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal) seems to be dominant tag with 598 posts whereas [cabal-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal-install) has 97.