# Should [cabal] and [cabal-install] be synonymous, or: When is disambiguation futile?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

The broader question in the subtitle is illustrated by [cabal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal) and [cabal-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal-install), two closely related tags about Haskell packages. Their current tag wiki excerpts are accurate:

- [cabal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal) (56 followers, 1352 questions): "Cabal is a package distribution and build system for the Haskell programming language" -- that includes the Cabal format for packages, the .cabal configuration files that specify such packages, and the Cabal library that handles them.
- [cabal-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal-install) (12 followers, 266 questions): "cabal-install is a package manager and dependency resolver for building and installing Haskell libraries" -- it is a tool built upon the Cabal infrastructure mentioned above.

In principle, there is a meaningful distinction between the tags, which might be even be useful sometimes (for instance, [cabal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal) can be relevant to questions about [haskell-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-stack), an alternative build tool, even if cabal-install isn't involved at all). In practice, however, the situation is rather hopeless: the cabal-install executable is called `cabal`, and people often refer to cabal-install simply as "Cabal". That being so, most questions that should have the [cabal-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal-install) tag (either on its own or alongside [cabal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal)) have just [cabal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal) instead.

Given this scenario, I wonder if it would be better to throw in the towel and make [cabal-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal-install) a synonym of [cabal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cabal). We would thus, at the cost of losing a marginally useful distinction, avoid continued retagging busywork and indecision about which tags to use or follow. Or, to put it more broadly: at which point does tag disambiguation becomes too much of a Sisyphean job to be worth bothering with?

---

A related suggestion about the concrete case is [*Merge [cabal] and [cabal-install] tags*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253909/2751851), which went nowhere, presumably due to lack of available Haskellers. (By the way, feel free to chime in if you have thoughts about the matter, even if you aren't a [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) dweller.)