# Merge [implicit] and [implicits] to [scala-implicits]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The description of the tags says:

> [implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit)  An implicit in Scala is a function applied or a parameter provided without explicitly appearing in the source code.
>
> [implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicits)   Anything related to Scala implicit parameters or conversions

While merging them with each other is separate ([Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags)), there is also [scala-implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-implicits). I think that either all three tags should be merged or [implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit)/[implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicits) (merged and) extended to all languages.

Comment: To get one or both extended to all languages: edit the wiki/excerpt to remove the word "Scala". :).

Comment: At a glance: (1) It doesn't seem necessary to have both [implicit] and [implicits]. (2) The ambiguity between the "implicit parameter" and "implicit conversion" meanings is suboptimal, though it might be a case of people [giving up on disambiguation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363341/2751851). (3) The [tag:implicit-parameters] tag should also be considered if we are thinking of disambiguation or switching to language-agnostic tags. (While [tag:implicit-conversion] is probably too general to cover the specific Scala meaning involved here, [tag:implicit-parameters] feels less problematic.)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I wouldn't want to do so unilaterally. Plus I initially missed that [tag:scala-implicits] already exists :) So should this edit also include retagging the questions which are really specific to Scala?

Comment: Tangentially related: [*Merge \[partialfunction\] and \[partial-functions\] tags?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367203/2751851). (Cf. specially suggestion #5 in [my answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368987/2751851).)

Comment: I don't actually know anything about Scala -- that was more of a joke than anything else. That said, I don't think that removing Scala from the definition of the tag means it no longer applies to Scala, it only means it doesn't *only* apply to Scala. But frankly, I like @duplode's solution better.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents, after looking at it a bit more closely. (I know about Scala only from hearsay, so take it with a grain of salt.)

- Scala's implicit conversion and implicit class features seem distinctive enough to merit a tag of their own, and that tag probably should be [scala-implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-implicits).
- The tags [implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit) and [implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicits) aren't great fits for such a Scala-specific feature. That being so, it would be reasonable to de-scalafy them, migrating Scala questions to [scala-implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-implicits) as appropriate. (It might also be reasonable to burninated, if there are no well-defined specific meaning for them. That is a separate matter, though.)
- While Scala's implicit parameters feel like somewhat of a different beast to me, they appear to be commonly discussed in tandem with implicit conversions (for instance, cf. [this book chapter](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html)), and so it seems fair to keep questions about them under the [scala-implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-implicits) umbrella. In any case, nothing stops people from also using the language-agnostic [implicit-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit-parameters) tag in such questions, and [implicit-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit-conversion) also exists.

Here is a quick Scala-centric rundown of how the tags are currently being used:

- [implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit): 1139 questions, 778 of them tagged [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala).
- [implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicits): 169 questions, 164 of them tagged [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala).(Unlike [implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit), this seems straighforward to merge.)
- [scala-implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-implicits): 45 questions, 43 of them tagged [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala).
- [implicit-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit-conversion): 1420 questions, 442 of them tagged [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala). (Some extra work might be required here.)
- [implicit-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit-parameters): 20 questions, 16 of them tagged [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala).

My overall impression is that clarifying the meanings of the tags would be relatively simple, but the way questions are spread across the tags means there is some substantial amount of work to be done if we are to put them in line with the intended meanings. This seems roughly opposite to the [partialfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partialfunction) situation I had a look at [in another question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367203/2751851), which is simple to solve except for the right thing to do not being entirely obvious.

(On a blatantly off-topic note, your input, as well as that of other [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) regulars, in that [partialfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partialfunction) Meta question would be much appreciated :))

Comment: "169 questions, 778 of them tagged scala" That would be a nice trick :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov It's just that the other 609 ones are implicitly tagged [scala] :) (Fixed, thanks!)